# can you assign initial value to global static variable in C?

Tags: c

I have a global variable "count". All I want to do is increment it each time the loop runs. Is there a potential problem with initializing static count as 0? How is this works in C?

```
static unsigned short count = 0;
while(1)
{
    count++;
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Yes, so long as the initializer is a constant expression.  You can't initialize with a function call for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, why did you think you can't? But if the value is `0` you can skip the initialization since `static` variables are automatically initialized to `0`. Also, as @[M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) [commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687645/can-you-assign-initial-value-to-global-static-variable-in-c#comment57122054_34687645) it's mandatory that the value is a constant, you can't assign the result of `malloc()` for instance.

There is no potential problem, and there is no reason to think that there would be a problem. Except integer overflow, in your code that's pretty sure going to happen but it has nothing to do with the storage class of your variable.